# Disable FlexPaper mouse wheel zoom

Tags: mousewheel, flexpaper

Always when i try to scroll up or down on a page with the FlexPaper HTML5 viewer it zoom in/out. How can I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible to disable Mouse Wheel zooming using our latest version of Desktop Publisher. Tick the option in the left bottom corner of the publisher to disable it. The publisher will produce the UIConfig file you will need to use in your viewer to disable the mouse wheel zoom.

You can grab the latest version from here:
http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/download/

Answer (score 1):

Set

**MaxZoomSize : 1**

in $('#documentViewer').FlexPaperViewer

Comment: I don't want to disable general zoom, only the possibility to zoom with the mouse wheel.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a UI config XML file you can use the "disableMouseWheel" setting, eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <FlexPaper_Zine_UIConfiguration>
    <desktop>
      <general disableMouseWheel="true"
```